# tf-idf document clustering with K-means in Apache Spark putting points into one cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, k-means, tf-idf

I am trying to do the classic job of clustering text documents by pre-processing, generating tf-idf matrix, and then applying K-means. However, testing this workflow on the classic 20NewsGroup dataset results in most documents being clustered into one cluster. (I have initially tried to cluster all documents from 6 of the 20 groups - so expecting to cluster into 6 clusters).

I am implementing this in Apache Spark as my purpose is to utilise this technique on millions of documents. Here is the code written in Pyspark on Databricks:

```
#declare path to folder containing 6 of 20 news group categories
path = "/mnt/%s/20news-bydate.tar/20new-bydate-train-lessFolders/*/*" % 
MOUNT_NAME

#read all the text files from the 6 folders. Each entity is an entire 
document. 
text_files = sc.wholeTextFiles(path).cache()

#convert rdd to dataframe
df = text_files.toDF(["filePath", "document"]).cache()

from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer, CountVectorizer 

#tokenize the document text
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="document", outputCol="tokens")
tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df).cache()

from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover

remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="tokens", 
outputCol="stopWordsRemovedTokens")
stopWordsRemoved_df = remover.transform(tokenized).cache()

hashingTF = HashingTF (inputCol="stopWordsRemovedTokens", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=200000)
tfVectors = hashingTF.transform(stopWordsRemoved_df).cache()    

idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features", minDocFreq=5)
idfModel = idf.fit(tfVectors)

tfIdfVectors = idfModel.transform(tfVectors).cache()

#note that I have also tried to use normalized data, but get the same result
from pyspark.ml.feature import Normalizer
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

normalizer = Normalizer(inputCol="features", outputCol="normFeatures")
l2NormData = normalizer.transform(tfIdfVectors)

from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans

# Trains a KMeans model.
kmeans = KMeans().setK(6).setMaxIter(20)
km_model = kmeans.fit(l2NormData)

clustersTable = km_model.transform(l2NormData)
```

[image: output showing most documents get clustered into cluster 0]

```
ID number_of_documents_in_cluster
0    3024
3    5
1    3
5    2
2    2
4    1
```

As you can see most of my data points get clustered into cluster 0, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong as all the tutorials and code I have come across online point to using this method.

In addition I have also tried normalizing the tf-idf matrix before K-means but that also produces the same result. I know cosine distance is a better measure to use, but I expected using standard K-means in Apache Spark would provide meaningful results.

Can anyone help with regards to whether I have a bug in my code, or if something is missing in my data clustering pipeline?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the implementation in python which does not group all documents together even with a high number of max features:

```
#imports
import pandas as pd
import os
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import numpy as np

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans 

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=200000, lowercase=True,
                             min_df=5, stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['document'])

#Apply K-means to create cluster
from time import time

km = KMeans(n_clusters=20, init='k-means++', max_iter=20, n_init=1,
            verbose=False)

km.fit(X)

#result
3     2634
6     1720
18    1307
15     780
0      745
1      689
16     504
8      438
7      421
5      369
11     347
14     330
4      243
13     165
10     136
17     118
9      113
19     106
12      87
2       62
```

I would have thought that we could replicate something similar in pyspark using KMeans with Euclidean distance before trying cosine or Jaccard distances in KMeans. Any solutions or comments?

Comment: have you tried changing your epsilon to a higher number? That would help limit clusters merging together `.setEpsilon` http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Understanding-epsilon-in-KMeans-td5757.html has a bit of an explanation

Comment: Apache spark has the method: kmeans.getTol()/setTol for getting and setting the tol value. This is set to 0.0001 by default. I believe this value is what needs to be set as I could not find any reference to the method setEpsilon. However, since the same approach and tol value manages to cluster document in python using sklearn - I don't think modifying this will help.

Comment: I have solved this problem using Sklearn in python, using the same approach of building tf-idf matrix and using K-means algorithm. Can anyone advise as to why it is failing in spark - is there an error in my pyspark code?

Comment: what version of python / spark are you using?

Comment: I am using spark 2.1. Currently I implement this on Databricks community edition.

Comment: @javid did you ever solve this? I am currently dealing with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: My problem was indeed high dimensionality, as indicated by one of the answers. Performing PCA first solved my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few quick comments:

- K-Means isn't the best algorithm for text analysis in general since it can perform badly at high dimensions.  I'd recommend LDA instead.
- With K-Means, if you decrease the number of features to maybe 2000, then you're more likely to get multiple distinct clusters.  (I tried this quickly on the 20news dataset provided in Databricks CE at /databricks-datasets/news20.binary/data-001/training and was able to get distinct clusters.)
- Unrelated: MLlib code can be less verbose if you put all of the transformers and K-Means into a Pipeline and then only call fit() and transform() once.  : )

Here's the code I modified from yours can ran.  Caveat: I have not tuned it at all, so the clusters are currently pretty useless (but it does find distinct clusters).

```
df = spark.read.parquet("/databricks-datasets/news20.binary/data-001/training")
df.cache().count()

from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer, CountVectorizer, StopWordsRemover
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="tokens")
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="tokens", outputCol="stopWordsRemovedTokens")
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="stopWordsRemovedTokens", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=2000)
idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features", minDocFreq=5)

from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(k=20)

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, remover, hashingTF, idf, kmeans])

model = pipeline.fit(df)

results = model.transform(df)
results.cache()

display(results.groupBy("prediction").count())  # Note "display" is for Databricks; use show() for OSS Apache Spark
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I understand K Means is not the best but I require it to be done on micro-text documents before applying LDA. I also understand that standard Kmeans with Euclidean distance is not the best, but I am trying to get this to work as research papers have mentioned they used it as a baseline.

Comment: Whilst reducing the number of features to say 2000 does reduce the dimensions, my Python implementation  added in the original questions does not cause all the documents to group together in one cluster - and that is with max_features=200000 – do you know any reasons why the python implementation with sklearn produces an output more in line with expectation?

Comment: Well, that's a good question.  : )  I haven't had time to explore it myself, but I'd guess the 2 pipelines are doing feature processing differently.  I'd recommend isolating the difference by doing feature preprocessing in 1 library and then passing those feature vectors to the 2 libraries.  It'd also be good to check the default parameters for the various transformers and K-Means.  If that still shows a major difference, it's probably in the initialization, which *is* different between the 2 algorithms (because of doing local vs distributed algorithms).

Comment: I haven't been able to take the pre-processed output from sklearn and feed it into spark k-means, or take the pre-processed output from spark and feed it into sk-learn kmeans. But since the pre-processing in both cases is the same, I would have to say that I am more inclined to think that the spark implementation of kmeans is not working correctly for text clustering

Comment: my current solution has been to take the pyspark dataframe, convert it to pandas dataframe and then use sklearn library to do the clustering - which works excellently! However, this of course is not a parallel solution that I can utilise on Big data sets which I will have to do in the near future. Hopefully the guys at apache spark can fix this issue.

Comment: If any spark developer can look into clustering 20 newsgroup data using spark k-means please let me know, as I would be interested to see if anyone else is having the same problem in k-means clustering of documents in spark verse doing it sklearn

Answer (score 1):

@Nassir,
Spark k-means(scala mllib api) is consistently producing highly skewed cluster size distributions in my experiments as well(see figure 1).  Majority of the data-points are assigned to one cluster. This experiment was conducted using the 20 Newsgroup data for which ground truth is available: the ~10K data-points were manually categorized into fairly balanced 20 groups. http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/

Initially I suspected that the vector creation step (using Spark's HashingTF and IDF libraries) was the cause of the incorrect clustering.  However, even after implementing my own version of TF-IDF based vector representation I still got similar clustering results with highly skewed size distribution.

Eventually I implemented my own version of k-means on top of spark which uses standard TF-IDF vector representation and (-ve) cosine similarity as the distance metric.  The results from this k-means look right.  See the Figure 2 below.

Additionally, I experimented by plugging in Euclidean distance as a similarity metric (to my own version of kmean) and results continue look right, not as skewed as spark k-means.

[figure 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkcIZ.png)

Comment: Great to see someone else was able to reproduce the error. I couldn't get folks in spark to look properly or resolve this issue  - which I think is pretty major being a spark mllib library function that is being used a lot. I will implement your code in future and see if I get similar results, and if it then works on twitter data sets where the original problem space was.

Comment: @Nassir, sure. The custom k-mean implemented is on private repo, I can share it with you, let me know your git handle. Which twitter dataset are you referring to? Does it have gold standard for clustering?